# How to build a Gi checker?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu

A Gi checker is an object used for check that the Gi meet IBJJF kimono requirement.

How to do your own Gi checker?

[image: Gi Checker dimensions]

Comment: Wouldn't this question be more appropriate on [Home Improvement SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com)? Or does the construction require specific martial arts knowledge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I make them here in the US.  They need to be made from a stable wood, like 1/4 sawn white oak.  You will need several woodworking machine tools if you want to make them accurately.  They are a gauge after all.  You will need a good band saw, table saw, surface planer, digital caliper for accurate measuring your machine set-up, sand paper and oil base finish.
Start by truing up your piece of wood to the exact outside dimensions.
Mark up several scrap pieces for each of the dimensions and then sneak up on the exact number little by lite until the machine tool you are using has been "dialed in".  Then carefully cut out the areas that do the checking.
[image]

[image]

If you have more questions you can get a hold of me at
ernstpeischl@gmail.com

Just be very careful when you are working with woodworking power tools.  Always wear safety glasses and use appropriate push sticks.

[image]

I hope that helps.

Ernst